# TFS 2018 on premise behind proxy service hooks notification failure

Tags: service, tfs, notifications, hook

since few days, service hooks all fail to notificate (PR updates, Work Item comments and so on) with this error and I don't know why.
TFS is installed on a domain machine (active directory) and had no problems so far.
The funny thing is that if I test in the Service Hook it does work
[image: Service Hook Trigger Test]

Slack or Teams. Doesn't matter.
Any ideas?

```
Error Details
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the 
request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because 
the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 
143.204.9.158:443
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, 
Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState 
state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, 
TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult 
ar)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 
.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Common.HttpActionTask. 
<RunAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
```